# Function is not returning when a record already exists in CoreData Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have this function that gets called by `firebase .childAdded observer`and I 'm trying to check if the record to write is already in database before it writes it. This is because when user logs in, all the incoming snapshots will cause multiple entry in database. 
The way I'm trying to perform the check is with `.contains`bool against the record, if it does than function should return, else it will go on and write the new record, but is not working, at every login it will adda all the incoming snapshots. What should I do instead? Many thanks as always.
This is the function:

```
static func saveBooking(bookingId: String, bookingDate: String, bookingStart: String, bookingEnd: String, customerName: String, price: String, workList: String) throws {
        let context = CoreData.databaseContext

        let request: NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()
        do {
            let fetch = try context.fetch(request)
            print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       fetching user")

            for value in fetch {
                if value.name == UserDetails.fullName {
                    print("User is: \(value.name!)")  //correct


                    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                        let booking = Booking(context: context)
                        booking.user?.name = value.name!

                        booking.bookingId = bookingId
                        booking.bookingDate = bookingDate
                        booking.bookingStart = bookingStart
                        booking.bookingEnd = bookingEnd
                        booking.customerName = customerName
                        booking.bookingPrice = price
                        booking.worksList = workList
                        if value.bookings!.contains(booking){
                            print("@@@@@@@@@   found existing record for this booking! ")
                            return

                        } else {
                            value.addToBookings(booking)
                            print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  booking user at propertis value attribution is : \(String(describing: booking.user!.name!))")
                            do {
                                try context.save()
                                print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  booking user after saving booking is : \(String(describing: booking.user!.name!))")
                                print("@@@@@@@@@@@@    New booking is saved")
                            } catch  {
                                print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    Error saving new booking")
                                print(error)
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        // Fallback on earlier versions
                        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Booking", in: context)
                        let booking = Booking(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: context)
                        booking.user?.name = value.name
                        booking.bookingId = bookingId
                        booking.bookingDate = bookingDate
                        booking.bookingStart = bookingStart
                        booking.bookingEnd = bookingEnd
                        booking.customerName = customerName
                        booking.bookingPrice = price
                        booking.worksList = workList
                        if value.bookings!.contains(booking) {
                            print("@@@@@@@@@   found existing record for this booking! ")
                            return
                        } else {
                            value.addToBookings(booking)
                            do {
                                try context.save()
                                print("@@@@@@@@@@@@    New booking is saved")
                            } catch  {
                                print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    Error saving new booking")
                                print(error)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch  {
            print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      Error in fetching a user")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line `let booking = Booking(context: context)` is creating a new `Booking` and inserting it into the context. This is always happening (as it is before your condition). This newly created `Booking` is NEVER part of the `value.booking` set - (how could it be it was just created!) - so it is always added.

I think what you want instead is

```
if value.bookings!.contains{ $0.bookingId == bookingId) {
    let booking = Booking(context: context)
    value.addToBookings(booking)
    booking.user?.name = value.name!
    ....
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, my condition is after the creation of new `Booking` and I do want create new  `Booking`only if condition fails, hence it doesn't exist. Thank you for pointing that out. The problem now is that the line  `if value.bookings!.contains {$0.bookingId == bookingId} {` throws me an error : `Expression type 'Bool' is ambiguous without more context`. What kind of context  do you think is missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up performing the check for existing record in a more classic way using `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchResult>` and `NSPredicate`but I'd like to understand how to use and explore the solution suggested by Jon Rose, that actually has been greatly useful as I didn't realise that I was creating a new object anyway.
I'm hoping that this will help others.
So the function is now written as :

```
static func saveBooking(bookingId: String, bookingDate: String, bookingStart: String, bookingEnd: String, customerName: String, price: String, workList: String) throws {
        let context = CoreData.databaseContext
        let request: NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()
        do {
            let fetch = try context.fetch(request)
            print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       fetching user")
            for userValue in fetch {
                if userValue.name == UserDetails.fullName {
                    print("User is: \(userValue.name!)")  //correct

                    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Booking")
                    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "bookingId == %@", bookingId)
                    request.predicate = predicate
                    request.fetchLimit = 1

                    do{
                        let count = try context.count(for: request)
                        if(count > 0){
                            //  matching object
                            print("@@@@@@@@@@@@ booking is already recorded")
                            return
                        }
                        else{
                            print("@@@@@@@@@@@@    booking is new")
                            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                                let booking = Booking(context: context)
                                booking.user?.name = userValue.name!
                                booking.bookingId = bookingId
                                booking.bookingDate = bookingDate
                                booking.bookingStart = bookingStart
                                booking.bookingEnd = bookingEnd
                                booking.customerName = customerName
                                booking.bookingPrice = price
                                booking.worksList = workList
                                userValue.addToBookings(booking)
                            } else {
                                // Fallback on earlier versions
                                let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Booking", in: context)
                                let booking = Booking(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: context)
                                booking.user?.name = userValue.name!
                                booking.bookingId = bookingId
                                booking.bookingDate = bookingDate
                                booking.bookingStart = bookingStart
                                booking.bookingEnd = bookingEnd
                                booking.customerName = customerName
                                booking.bookingPrice = price
                                booking.worksList = workList
                                userValue.addToBookings(booking)

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            do {
                try context.save()
                print("@@@@@@@@@@@@    New booking is saved")
            } catch  {
                print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    Error saving new booking")
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```